# C curses doesn't catch mouse event

Tags: c, mouseevent, ncurses, curses

I am trying to implement a scroll up and down in a curse program, at the moment I am just trying to catch the event and display it's number:

```
MEVENT event;
mousemask(ALL_MOUSE_EVENTS, NULL);

while (ch != 126)
{
  ch=wgetch (current->child);
  switch(ch)
  {
    case KEY_MOUSE:
      if(getmouse(&event) == OK)
          wprintw (current->child, "\nmouse event: %d\n", event.bstate);
      break;
    default:
          wprintw (current->child, "key: %d\n", ch);
  }
  wrefresh (current->child );
}
```

`has_mouse()` returns `1`, but the events aren't catched, no click, no mouse wheel...

Also I'm using `ncurses 6.0.4` so mouse wheel should be supported.

Comment: Nope, linux. I just figured it out finding a post after searching for another time! It needs `keypad` set to `true`. Now it works. There's still one thing missing, I'm able to catch mouse scrolling up with `BUTTON4_PRESSED` but the scrolling down isn't captured in any button event (I try them all in a big `if`/`else if`).

Answer (score 0):

Lack of ability to capture wheel-mouse sounds like an ncurses5 application.  The feature works in xterm (and programs which implement xterm-style mouse-controls).  There's not enough information in the question to guess which type of problem is preventing you from seeing the mouse events.

There's no such thing as "ncurses 6.0.4".  ncurses versions have a major, minor and patch-date.   At the moment, the most recent development version is [6.0.20160423](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/NEWS.html#t20160423)